# Placing 2 Divs side by side and css code compression

Tags: html, css, button, navbar

I have been trying to learn css for about 2 months now and I have stumbled upon not being able to place these 2 divs on the same line. My logo goes on the header bar but my login button will not go on it?

Also if you guy's could tell me ways to shorten my css code to do the same thing that would also be fantastic!

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700);
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.headerMenu {
    background-color: #00B9ED;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
}
#logo {
 margin-left: 15%;
}
#logo a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00B9ED;
  moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 60%;
}
#nav p {
 margin-top: 8%;
}
#nav a {
 color: white;
}

#nav a:link {text-decoration:none}
#nav a:visited { text-decoration:none}
#nav a:hover {text-decoration:none; opacity: 0.6;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Daily Quotes</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="headerMenu">
            <div id="logo">
                <h2><a href="#">Daily Quotes</a></h2>
            </div>
   <div id="nav">
   <p><a href="#">login</a></p>
   </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A few tips (because you asked): 1. You don't have to keep specifying the same font on each element; just specify it on the parent. 2. `auto` is not a valid property for `padding`. 3. Also, you probably don't need to use so many vendor prefixes, `box-shadow` and `border-radius` are now extremely well supported. 4. You don't need to set `width: 100%` on relatively positioned block-level elements.

Comment: Alright so you said specify it on the parent? The parent of the 2 divs would be .headermenu correct?

Comment: That's correct. I would highly recommend reading up about block-level elements: http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/. Basically it sounds like you expect the two divs to simply sit next to each other, and that's not how block level elements work. You'll need to float them, position them absolutely, or use `display: inline-block`

Comment: Alright thanks! I will read up on that article now.

Comment: No worries, hopefully that link explains it a bit more. Also do some research on floats, that should help you get your head around what's actually happening: https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting float:left; on your #logo

```
#logo {
    margin-left: 15%;
    float:left;
}
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700);
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.headerMenu {
    background-color: #00B9ED;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px #000000;
}
#logo {
 margin-left: 15%;
     float:left;
}
#logo a {
    padding-top: 3px;
    height: 38px;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav {
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #00B9ED;
  moz-border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  border: 3px solid #e5e5e5;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 60%;
}
#nav p {
 margin-top: 8%;
}
#nav a {
 color: white;
}

#nav a:link {text-decoration:none}
#nav a:visited { text-decoration:none}
#nav a:hover {text-decoration:none; opacity: 0.6;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Daily Quotes</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="headerMenu">
            <div id="logo">
                <h2><a href="#">Daily Quotes</a></h2>
            </div>
   <div id="nav">
   <p><a href="#">login</a></p>
   </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```